# Unknown issue with insert statment

Tags: forms, vba, insert, stat, subform

I have a sub form with staff records on it within a main form. I am trying to allow the user to select a record from the sub form and add it to a table, here is my code which, to me, looks correct. However it gives me an error saying "Syntax error in INSERT INTO"

```
Private Sub Command3_Click()
Dim dbs As Database
Dim sqlstr As String
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Forename = Nz(Forms!frm_Capex_Submission!frm_staffSub.Form.shy_forename, "")
Surname = Nz(Forms!frm_Capex_Submission!frm_staffSub.Form.shy_surname, "")
emp_no = Nz(Forms!frm_Capex_Submission!frm_staffSub.Form.shy_empno, "")
CAP_ID = Forms!frm_Capex_Submission!CAP_ID

sqlstr = "INSERT INTO tbl_CapexStaff ( Forename, Surname, EmployeeID, CAP_ID) )" _
& " SELECT '" & Nz(Me!shy_forename, "") & "' AS Expr1, '" & Nz(Me!shy_surname, "") & "' AS Expr2, '" & Nz(Me!shy_empno, "") & " AS Expr3, " & Forms!frm_Capex_Submission.CAP_ID & " as expr4, """
dbs.Execute (sqlstr)
tbl_CapexStaff.Requery
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra ")" in your query

> > INSERT INTO tbl_CapexStaff ( Forename, Surname, EmployeeID, CAP_ID) )

Comment: Ohh, I didn't even notice that! Thanks a lot But now I have another error;
Runtime error 3075
Syntax error in string in query expression (expr3 and 4)
So I think there's a problem with the last 2 expressions
Any ideas? Cheers

Comment: You forgot to add a single quote before AS `in Nz(Me!shy_empno, "") & "' AS Expr3`

Comment: Cheers, I made a few tweaks including that and it worked for 1 record but then after trying to add another it doesn't add
'sqlstr = "INSERT INTO tbl_CapexStaff ( Forename, Surname, EmployeeID, CAP_ID)" _
& " SELECT '" & Nz(Me!shy_forename, "") & "' AS Expr1, '" & Nz(Me!shy_surname, "") & "' AS Expr2, " & Nz(Me!shy_empno, "") & " AS Expr3, " & Nz(Forms!frm_Capex_Submission.CAP_ID, "") & " AS Expr4;"
dbs.Execute (sqlstr)
'